# Storing rows from a MySQL table into an array in Java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to store rows from a table into an array. I can get the first result and store that but I cannot seem to be able to store any of the other data.

This is the code I've written

```
try 
    {
        test = "select * from Arsenal order by 'MatchNumber' ASC";                
        rs = st.executeQuery(test); 

        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            //This retrieves each row of Arsenal table and adds it to an array in the Team Results class.

            matchno = rs.getString("MatchNumber");                    
            hometeam = rs.getString("HomeTeam");                      
            awayteam = rs.getString("AwayTeam");                         
            homegoals = rs.getString("HomeGoals");                   
            awaygoals = rs.getString("AwayGoals");                   
            result = rs.getString("Result");                             


            teams = (matchno + "," + hometeam + "," + awayteam + "," + homegoals + "," + awaygoals + "," + result);     // Takes all the variables containging a single customers information and puts it into a string, seperated by commas.
            TeamResults.add(matchno,hometeam,awayteam,homegoals,awaygoals,result);
        }
    }
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `while`-condition to `hasNext()` and use `next()` inside of the loop to move the database cursor forward.

Comment: Thats Totally Wrong, `next()` is responsible for Moving the cursor froward one row from its current position, so he don't need to change it, also There is no `hasNext()` method available in `ResultSet` class

Comment: Yes, just as I wrote.

Comment: `while (rs.hasNext()) { rs.next(); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method bellow  :

```
 public void SelectData(String sqlcounter ,String sql){

        try {
         RsCounter=stmt.executeQuery(sqlcounter);
            System.out.println(sqlcounter);
            while(RsCounter.next()){

                countrow=RsCounter.getInt("COUNTR");
                System.out.println(countrow+"\n");
                             }
            System.out.println(sql);
         RsSelecting = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         data=new String[countrow][RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];

         header= new String[RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];

     i=0;
     while(RsSelecting.next()){
      for(j=0;j<RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnCount();j++){

              data[i][j]=(RsSelecting.getString(j+1));
              header[j]=RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnName(j+1);
              System.out.print(data[i][j]+"\n");

     }    


      i++;

     }
      i=j=0;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                       ex.printStackTrace();

            Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
```

where

```
sqlcounter ="select COUNT(*) as COUNTR from Arsenal order by 'MatchNumber' ASC";
```

and

```
sql ="select * from Arsenal order by 'MatchNumber' ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the column names once. Sometimes `ALIAS` doesn't work out, I am not sure why.

Get the meta data from the result set:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int size = metaData.getColumnCount();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(i);
```

Also just for performance, list out the column names instead of using `*` in the `SELECT` query. Also, you can take a look at `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.` It's used like:

```
CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
crs.populate(resultSet);
```

I think it also implements `CachedRowSet`, but I am not entirely sure.